# Fixing corrupted WinCE 6.0 from USB or SD card

Tags: filesystems, windows-ce, fat32

I have an ARM v4 device with touchscreen running Windows Embedded 6.0.

I am developing new app for it (as a replacement for the old one). Everything worked correctly but **I accidentally renamed file that was intended to run at startup** (if it helps it is autorun.exe in /NAND folder) **and now the Win does not start**.

At startup error is shown and after clicking OK the process is stuck.

**I need to revert this change (rename file back) but how to do it?**
I cannot connect to the device anymore with Visual Studio, Remote File/Registry Viewer or similar tool as the conman is not running and I cannot run them (because Windows is not started yet, obviously).

Is there any way how to run cmd line or some tool from SD Card or USB or Ethernet where I can execute some command to rename file back?

I do not have the OS image or the knowledge to build it from scratch, that is too complicated for me.

Comment: can't you simply connect your compact flash to your pc with a card reader, and rename the file?

Comment: @salvolds The device is running without the SD card - the system is stored on internal NAND. I inserted new SD card with NK.bin file as an attempt to reinstall the system - but nothing happened.

Comment: Ok I see. Are you using the tool provided by your device vendor to format and prepare the disk with your nk.bin?